# ReactJS Stores - this.context.getStore is not a function(…)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have:

```
import React from 'react';
import FilterButton from './FilterButton';
import FilterJobsScreen from '../../actions/jobs-screen/FilterJobsScreen';

import JobStore from '../../stores/JobStore';

export default class RightPanel extends React.Component {

    static contextTypes = {
        getStore: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
    };

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.setState({
            counts: this.context.getStore(JobStore).getCounts()
        });
        this.context.getStore(JobStore).on('change', () => {
            this.setState({
                counts: this.context.getStore(JobStore).getCounts()
            });
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.load();
    }

    load() {

    }

    onClick(e) {
        var filters_array = this.state.filters;
        var idx = filters_array.indexOf(e);
        if (idx === -1) {
            filters_array.push(e);
        } else {
            filters_array.splice(idx, 1);
        }
        this.setState({
            filters: filters_array
        })
        this.context.executeAction(FilterJobsScreen, this);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="controls">
                    <span className="title">Filters</span>
                    <FilterButton onClick={this.onClick.bind(this, 'My jobs')} name='My jobs'
                                  count={this.state.counts.my_jobs} active={true}/>
                    <FilterButton onClick={this.onClick.bind(this, 'Not approved')} name='Not approved'
                                  count={this.state.counts.not_approved}/>
                    <FilterButton onClick={this.onClick.bind(this, 'Supply')} name='Supply'
                                  count={this.state.counts.supply}/>
                    <FilterButton onClick={this.onClick.bind(this, 'Repair')} name='Repair'
                                  count={this.state.counts.repair}/>
                    <FilterButton onClick={this.onClick.bind(this, 'Service exchange')} name='Service exchange'
                                  count={this.state.counts.service_ex}/>
                    <FilterButton onClick={this.onClick.bind(this, 'Urgent')} name='Urgent'
                                  count={this.state.counts.urgent}/>
                    <FilterButton onClick={this.onClick.bind(this, 'Today')} name='Today'
                                  count={this.state.counts.today}/>
                    <FilterButton onClick={this.onClick.bind(this, 'Overdue')} name='Overdue'
                                  count={this.state.counts.overdue}/>
                </div>
                <div className="controls">
                    <span className="title">Sorts</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
};

RightPanel.contextTypes = {
    executeAction: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default RightPanel;
```

But when I try to load the page it is giving me the error:

```
this.context.getStore is not a function
```

But I bring that in up top:

```
static contextTypes = {
        getStore: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
    };
```

Where am I going wrong?

---

Here is my store:

```
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';

class JobStore extends EventEmitter {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.jobs = new Map();
        this.counts = {};
    }

    handleJobsData(payload) {
        console.log(payload)
        if (payload.clear === true) {
            this.jobs = new Map();
        }
        payload.data.jobs.forEach((job) => {
            this.jobs.set(job.id, job);
        });
        this.counts = payload.data.counts;

        this.emit('change');

    }

    getCounts() {
        return this.counts;
    }

    getJobs() {
        return this.jobs;
    }

    dehydrate () {
        return this.jobs;
    }

    rehydrate (state) {

    }

}

JobStore.dispatchToken = null;

JobStore.handlers = {
    'RECEIVED_JOBS_DATA': 'handleJobsData'
};

JobStore.storeName = 'JobStore';

export default JobStore;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but after removing:

```
RightPanel.contextTypes = {
    executeAction: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default RightPanel;
```

It works.

And changed the top to:

```
static contextTypes = {
        getStore: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        executeAction: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
    };
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to change your constructor, because you receive your props and context through the constructor method parameters:

```
constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
}
```

Without doing this your properties and context object will be lost.

Comment: The next problem you have is that you overwrite your context types. RightPanel.contextTypes and the static declaration are equal. This is the reason for the correct result after moving the ContextTypes in your class.